# ¿Al crear mi elemento html de forma automatizada con c# este es remplazado y no agregado?

Tags: c#, html5

Lo que quiero hacer es crear varias filas con sus respectivos elemento dentro de un accordeon, a continuacion les dejo el codigo que pongo en mi evento `clicserver`

```
public string RowsAdd = "";
            RowsAdd += "<section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'> <label>Titulo</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Descripcion</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Horas</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Seccion</label></section><section class='col-lg-1'><label>Hecho</label></section></section><section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'><input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section><section class='col-lg-2'><textarea rows='5' class='form-control mandatory'></textarea></section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='number' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <input type='checkbox' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; ' runat='server' ID='addRow' OnServerClick='addRow_OnServerClick'> Agregar </button> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; '> Remover </button> </section> </section><span>&nbsp;</span>";
            contantRows.InnerHtml = RowsAdd;
```

El problema es que si lo realiza pero en vez de poner el resultado de esa consulta debajo de mi otra fila, lo reemplaza y cada vez que le doy en agregar otra fila nueva siempre se queda en uno porque no me la pone debajo sino que reemplaza a la actual.

codigo Html:

```
<div style="height: auto;" runat="server" ID="contantRows">

    <section class="col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer" id="seccionador">

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <label> Titulo </label>
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <label> Descripcion </label>
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <label> Horas </label>
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <label> Seccion </label>
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-1">
            <label> Hecho </label>
        </section>

    </section>

    <section class="col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer">
        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mandatory" />
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control mandatory"></textarea>
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control mandatory" />
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mandatory" />
        </section>
        <section class="col-lg-1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control mandatory" />
        </section>

        <section class="col-lg-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 0px;" runat="server" ID="addRow"
            OnServerClick="addRow_OnServerClick"> Agregar </button>
        </section>
        <section class="col-lg-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 0px;"> Remover </button>
        </section>
    </section>
    <span>&nbsp; </span>
</div>
```

Comment: que valor tiene `RowsAdd` ? contiene lo que había antes en `contantRows`?

Comment: @aloMalbarez amm nooo se inicializa con una cadena vacía.

Comment: pues parece ser eso `contantRows.InnerHtml = RowsAdd;` va a contener la última row nomas

Comment: @aloMalbarez entonces crees que sea una buena idea ir guardando todo el código html en un .txt y leerlo cada que se agregue un elemento nuevo?

Comment: linea 1 , cada vez que pasa por ahi tu RowsAdd  queda vacia, "RowsAdd +=" no sirve de nada

Comment: yo lo armaría en javascript client side hasta que haga el post, pero si lo necesitas del lado del server (validar sanitizar etc) podes guardar la info en un array o estructura similar, o directamente el html en texto. lees el innerhtml le sumas lo nuevo y lo asignas nuevamente

Comment: cual sería el html que querés duplicar ? el segundo `.top-buffer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl RowsAdd = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");

RowsAdd.Attributes.Add("class","unaNuevaFila");

RowsAdd.InnerHtml = "<section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'> <label>Titulo</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Descripcion</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Horas</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Seccion</label></section><section class='col-lg-1'><label>Hecho</label></section></section><section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'><input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section><section class='col-lg-2'><textarea rows='5' class='form-control mandatory'></textarea></section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='number' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <input type='checkbox' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; ' runat='server' ID='addRow' OnServerClick='addRow_OnServerClick'> Agregar </button> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; '> Remover </button> </section> </section><span>&nbsp;</span>";

contantRows.Controls.Add(RowsAdd);
```

creas un nuevo div, le pones una class, le definis el innerhtml, y por ultimo  la agregas al  `contantRows`

Answer (score 1):

este es el problema:

**public string** RowsAdd = "";

estas redefiniendo tu variable local cada vez que entras en el ciclo o evento o clase o donde quiera que lo estes poniendo.

haz tu variable global al metodo o ciclo para no borrala

```
 public string RowsAdd ="";
 for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
 {
      RowsAdd += "<section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'> <label>Titulo</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Descripcion</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Horas</label></section><section class='col-lg-2'><label>Seccion</label></section><section class='col-lg-1'><label>Hecho</label></section></section><section class='col-lg-12 text-center top-buffer'><section class='col-lg-2'><input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section><section class='col-lg-2'><textarea rows='5' class='form-control mandatory'></textarea></section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='number' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <input type='text' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <input type='checkbox' class='form-control mandatory'/> </section> <section class='col-lg-2' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; ' runat='server' ID='addRow' OnServerClick='addRow_OnServerClick'> Agregar </button> </section> <section class='col-lg-1' > <button class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-top: 0px; '> Remover </button> </section> </section><span>&nbsp;</span>";
        contantRows.InnerHtml = RowsAdd;
 }
```

la otra opcion seria hacer tu innerHTML += para que no borres el resultado anterior

```
contantRows.InnerHtml += RowsAdd;
```

Comment: oye amm me sale este error  Cannot get inner content of contantRows because the contents are not literal. cuando le agrego contantRows.InnerHtml += RowsAdd;

Comment: es que contantRows tiene un runatserver

Comment: asi es, si el control no tiene runat=server y solo se maneja desde el lado del ciente no se podra acceder, 
tendras que mantener la variable RowsAdd sin borrarla o mandar el contantrows al lado del servidor